# Terraform Azure Devops Provider

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

We are trying to automate the Azure DevOps functions using Terraform. We are able to create Projects and Repos using Terraform. But we need to create multiple projects and repos specific to each project.

I have my terraform.tfvars file as given below

```
Proj1_Repos = ["Repo1","Repo2","Repo3"]
Proj2_Repos  = ["Repo4","Repo5","Repo7"]
Project_Name = ["Proj1","Proj2"]
```

How i can write my terraform configuration file to create Proj1_Repos in Proj1 and Proj2_Repos in Proj2

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have an easier time restructuring the variables to look something like:

```json
"Projects" = {
  "Proj1" = {
    "repos" = ["Repo1","Repo2","Repo3"]
  },
  "Proj2" = {
    "repos" = ["Repo4","Repo5","Repo6"]
  }
}
```

This way you can more cleanly iterate over your declarations using the [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) operator for your devops repo resources.

Alternatively, if restructuring the input variables isn't an option, you can use the `locals` block to construct an association map for your variables. [Something like this](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/produce-maps-from-list-of-strings-of-a-map/2197/2)

If you are looking for a way to feed a variable value to reference another variable, you will not be able to do so without constructing a custom data object using the key and value of your variables. This route can get pretty wonky and not recommended.